# How does a database commit work internally

Tags: sql, database, commit

I was wondering what happens internally in the DB once a commit is executed. I guess this depends on the database system, but what's the high level concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to below article for how transactions happen in RDBMS. But, every database has its own architecture of doing this, in their own way.

https://ecomputernotes.com/database-system/rdbms/transaction